# Flask and obtaining a full absolute path to a route

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking to integrate some API's through a web application interface, to achieve this I need to identify the absolute path for a specific route. As I dont want to hard code any urls I'd like to do this dynamically in the flask app.

I thought that should be simple enough and tried a couple of things:

```
abs_url = url_for('home')
```

This didn't work of course as it just returned the route. I since learnt that `url_for` requires the function name. It then returns the route ('/home' for example).

I then tried:

```
abs_url = redirect(url_for('home'))
```

This gave me a redirect object, I was hoping `path` may be a variable I could call, however that doesnt seem to be the case.

Google has not been my friend today and hasn't given me anything to go on and advice would be appreciated.

The more I think about this the more I think the simplest option would be to capture the application address as part of the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this I have captured the application address as part of the initial info gathering form.